# Continuous Integration and Release Management

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation

We are a small software development shop, small meaning one perm. software engineer and two contractors.  I am considering using a continuous integration and release management process since our product needs to be certified by the FDA.  Our development environment is WinCE 6.0, ARM 7, both using C/C++.  I am looking for recommendations for open source tools to improve our process.

We are using Subversion for our repository and in the process of setting up Bugzilla as well.  Would TeamCity be a good addition to this suite of tools?

Comment: sounds more like a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good luck with the FDA support; my company has been moving towards FDA certification and it is a crazy process.

I would definitely recommend setting up an automated build process as soon as possible in your development process; even if it is not a CI build process.  I have had experience setting up an automated build process in both new and existing code bases and it is much easier to implement a build process in a new code base. If you are planning on a build process from the beginning, you can make changes to the structures of your code\project files (I work with C#) so that it will make setting up a build process easier.

As for build servers, yes, I would recommend TeamCity.  I have been using it at my company for about a year to run a CI, nightly and QA build process.  Overall, it is a very easy tool to configure, use, and maintain.

I also know that Jenkins (Hudson) is a very popular build server. However, I do not have any experience using it, so I cannot give you a good comparison.

Hope this information helps.